# How to capture parent class 'this' in a child object getter in ES6 or later?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here is a simple JavaScript code:

```
class Test {
  constructor(val) {
    this._value = val;
    this.child = {
      get value() { return this._value; },
      getValue: () => { return this._value; }
    };
  }
}

let o = new Test(1);
console.log(o.child.value);
console.log(o.child.getValue());
```

The output:

```
undefined
1
```

In the child object `child`, I want to make the getter `get value()` to produce the same value as the lambda `getValue()`, i.e. to capture the parent's `this` properly and produce `1` rather than `undefined`.

Is there an elegant way of doing it within the `class`? Or should I use the lambda and give up on the getter?

I could probably do this:

```
    this.child = {
      parent: this, 
      get value() { return this.parent._value; },
    };
```

However I don't want to expose `child.parent`, only `child.value`.

Comment: why are you setting the child as a generic object, instead of a classed object that you pass the parent into? For that matter, why would the child be responsible for returning its parent's values? That's just bad code design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` and `child` are defined in the constructor, and `value` should be private, and accessed only via `child`. You can set `value` as a normal variable in the closure, and access it via the `child` getter and setter:

```js
class Test {
  constructor(val) {
    let value = val;
    this.child = {
      get value() { return value; },
      set value(v) { value = v; },
    };
  }
}

let o = new Test(1);
console.log(o.child.value);
o.child.value = 5;
console.log(o.child.value);
```

If you need the `value` inside `Test`, you can always access it via the `child`:

```js
class Test {
  constructor(val) {
    let value = val;
    this.child = {
      get value() { return value; },
      set value(v) { value = v; },
    };
  }
  
  get value() {
    return this.child.value;
  }
  
  set value(v) {
    this.child.value = v;
  }
}

let o = new Test(1);
console.log(o.value);
o.value = 5;
console.log(o.value);
```

Comment: A great answer but I need to access `this._value` from other methods of `Test` class. I.e., the parent class methods can change it, but the `child` object, which is passed as token somewhere else, can only expose it as read-only property.

Comment: If the child can also set the value, you can access it via the child. If not, than this won't work for you. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to myself, it can simply be done by capturing `this` inside `constructor`:

```
class Test {
  constructor(val) {
    const self = this;
    this._value = val;
    this.child = {
      get value() { return self._value; }
    };
  }
}
```